# How to get advertise-address of kubernetes apiserver from a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have installed Kubernetes 1.12 using kubeadm.

Is there a way to get advertise-address of kubernetes api-server from a pod?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't need that. From pods Kubernetes API is always available using URL https://kubernetes.default

Comment: Thanks @Vasily for your reply. Yeah I know we can access k8s api server from pod using "kubernetes.default" service (or using incluster config). But I need advertise-address. Okay my use case is that I want to generate a kubeconfig file from pod(where my api server is running) and send it back to client so that client can use this kubeconfig file to access k8s api server from outside of cluster.

Comment: try using "kubectl get --raw /api", it will give an address of apiserver.